# FaceBook SDK - Can't get app events to log at all?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, fbsdk

I've tried everything under the sun to get the Facebook SDK to log my app events. It appears as though everything is setup correctly, but when I go into the dev dashboard to do the events log test, nothing appears when I launch my app. Here's what I've done to set up the SDK:

**1**) **Imported the Facebook SDK and put the appropriate code into AppDelegate:**

**AppDelegate.m**

```
@import FBSDKCoreKit;
@import FBSDKLoginKit;
@import FBSDKShareKit;

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
     
        [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
        
        [FBSDKSettings setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled:YES];
        [FBSDKSettings setAutoLogAppEventsEnabled:YES];
        
    }
    
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
                openURL:(NSURL *)url
                options:(nonnull NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey, id> *)options
    {
      [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                     openURL:url
                                                     options:options];
         
      return YES;
    }
    
    - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
       
        [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
    
    }
```

**2**) **Updated info.plist with the following information:**

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb0000000000</string> (my app id)
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>0000000000</string> (my app id)
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>MyAppName</string>
<key>FacebookClientToken</key>
<string>MyAppName</string>
<key>FacebookAutoLogAppEventsEnabled</key>
<string>TRUE</string>
<key>FacebookAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled</key>
<string>TRUE</string>
```

***According to FB Documentation:***

[image]

**Note:** I'm confused because Facebook's documentation says to put your app name in the CLIENT-TOKEN spot... should this not be the Client Token found in the security section of the App dashboard?

**3. Registered my app in the Facebook Business/Developer Dashboard**

This is all done correctly; to confirm this, I did what facebook suggested and pasted this code into one of my View Controllers, and I'm able to 'login' and connect to FB via my app successfully.

```
FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
loginButton.center = self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview:loginButton];
```

Everything appears to be setup as it should be, but no matter what I do I can't get my app events to show in the Facebook events test. :/ Any help is appreciated! Thank you.